# Database problems using model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Again a question about CodeIgniter. I'm trying to get information out of my database, which is not that dificult. I get all the data but want to add an condition, the author_id has to be the same as $id. My code:

```
<?php
class BookModel extends CI_Model {

    public function get_book($id){
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT book_id, book_title, book_publisher, book_summary FROM books WHERE author_id = $id');
            return $query->result();
        }
}
?>
```

If I echo $id it shows my ID. But in the SQL function it is failing. Also, when i hardcode a number like

*WHERE author_id = 1*

It load proberly.

This is the error i get:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT book_id, book_title, book_publisher, book_summary FROM books
>   WHERE author_id = $id

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use = instead of ==

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of using `$this->load->database();` why not autoload so you dont have to place this `$this->load->database();` every where `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

Firstly, MySQL uses single = for both assignment and comparison, not ==.

Secondly, variables in PHP are parsed only in double-quoted strings, not single.

So `'...$id'` will be parsed literally as `$id`, not the *value* of the variable `$id`. Convert to double quotes.

Or, use CI binding - it's better for security, and you don't have to worry about escaping, quotes etc.

```
$sql = 'SELECT ... FROM books WHERE author_id = ?';
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
```

Comment: Fixed that, but it still don't work. The new error:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'

SELECT book_id, book_title, book_publisher, book_summary FROM books WHERE author_id = $id

Comment: Updated. You need to brush up on some basics, it seems. You have some elementary errors currently.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using codeigniter,use the ci database class functions,they will make your task simpler and you have not to worry for sql injection .You can do it in simpler way like this

```
    public function get_book($id)
      {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->select('book_id, book_title, book_publisher, book_summary');
        $this->db->from('books');
        $this->db->where('auther_id',$id);
        $data=$this->db->get();
        return $data->result();
       }
```

Comment: Thanx this was very helpful too! Do you know how it works with updating information. I'm really stuck in that :(

Comment: Here is the CI documentation for database calss function check them out 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html
    spend some time reading theme,i hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT book_id, book_title, book_publisher, book_summary FROM books WHERE author_id =".$id);
```